# Capturar Errores en mi Behaviour en WCF - C#

Tags: c#, controller, error404

Tengo un proyecto bastante avanzado de Backend donde he tenido que realizar un Behaviour para poder controlar varias cosas de las llamadas a una API externa.

Todo ha ido bien, y he podido unificar en un mismo sitio estos controles para todas las llamadas que se hacen sin necesidad de cambiar el codigo en todos los sitios donde se hacen estas llamadas.

El problema es que no se me capturar los errores 404 por ejemplo, o los 500.

Este es mi codigo:

Aqui seria un ejemplo de la llamada a la API externa:

```
protected virtual Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.RespuestaSNPV1201 RequestToVendor(VendorWebService vendor, string clientFiscalId, BasicSearchCriterion criteria)
{
    Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.RespuestaSNPV1201 result;

    try
    {
       using (Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.SNPV1201SoapClient client = new Vendor.Sinacofi.SinacofiService.SNPV1201SoapClient())
        {
        /*Credentials*/
        result = client.ConsultaRutificacion();
        }
    return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // control error
    }
```

Y aqui los dos archivos necesarios de mi Behaviour (la configuracion XML la omito)

```
namespace SIPE.Search.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Implements methods that can be used to extend run-time behavior for an endpoint in either a client application.
    /// </summary>
    public class ExternalClientBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new ExternalClientBehaviorClass();
        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get
            {
                return typeof(ExternalClientBehaviorClass);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// JSON REST[GET] Converter Behavior
        /// </summary>
        private class ExternalClientBehaviorClass : IEndpointBehavior
        {
            public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
            {                
            }

            public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
            {
                ExternalClientMessageInspector clientInspector = new ExternalClientMessageInspector(endpoint);
                clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(clientInspector);

                foreach (ClientOperation op in clientRuntime.Operations)
                {
                    op.ParameterInspectors.Add(clientInspector);
                }
            }

            public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
            {
                endpointDispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ExternalClientMessageInspector(endpoint));
            }

            public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Y donde realizo las cosas que quiero y donde me gustaria poder capturar los errores 404 al realizar la llamadas, y otros.

```
namespace SIPE.Search.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Intercepts send requests. 
    /// </summary>
    public class ExternalClientMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IParameterInspector, IErrorHandler
    {
        private ServiceEndpoint Endpoint { get; set; }

        Dictionary<string, object> inputsParam;

        public ExternalClientMessageInspector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            //empty
        }

        public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
        {
            ((Dictionary<string, string>)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items[operationName])).Add("OutputParam", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnValue));

        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            //code not necessary
        }

        public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
        {
            // code not neccesary
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();  // Create a copy to work with
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();         // Restore the original message

            return copy.GetReaderAtBodyContents().Name;
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            // no implement
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            // no implement
            return true;
        }

        public void NotifyError()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Ahora mismo los errores llegan al Excepction del metodo RequestToVEndor, pero como digo no quiero hacerlo ahi, ya que deberia de hacer lo mismo en muchisimos otros sitios.

A ver si me podeis echar una mano, ya que estoy seguro que falta alguna cosa clave.

Gracias

Edito para añadir mi archivo config de Behaviour ya que creo que por aqui tambien puede estar el problema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <!-- SPECIFIC BEHAVIOR EXTENSION FOR JSON URL DESERIALIZER-->
    <behavior name="ServiceRESTBehavior">
      <ConverterWebHttpBehaviourExtension />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ServiceSOAPBehavior" />
    <behavior name="ExternalDependencyBehavior">
      <ExternalClientBehavior/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>  
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Deberias entonces añadir `Try/Catch` en las funciones que quieres capturar los errores y gestionar desde allí éstos mismos

Comment: basicamente separas el Handler error como una nueva clase, en la configuracion lo agregas para establecer que en caso de error se use la implementacion de esta extension en todas las llamadas,revisa https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/5460/implementing-ierrorhandler-for-wcf-services

Comment: Valem estoy mirando... Pero no termino de verlo. Tiene que ser en una nueva clase? No puedo añadirlo a ExternalClientMessageInspector ???
Estoy intentando adaptarlo con el codigo que me has pasado, pero no me llega a entrar nunca en el metodo ApplyDispatchBehavior de la implementacion de IHadlerError que entiendo que es lo importante.

Comment: @MiguelZarate Eso que comentas es para los ServicesBehaviour, lo mio es un endpointBehaviour y  entra en el ApplyDispatchBehaviour... asi que no me vale.

Me encuentro muchos casos como el mio y sin respuesta, no se si es que estoy enfocando mal el problema.

Como digo la Interfaz IEndpointBehavior no dispara el ApplyDispachError por lo que no puedo añadir el "inspector del ErrorHandler".

He intentado añadirlo desde El ApplyClientBehaviour de diversas formas que he encontrado en la web, pero sin existo.